# Validity of testing the difference btwn 2 proportions with very low counts

Tags: statistical-power, fishers-exact-test

I want to compare the mortality in the treatment group and the placebo, to see if they are different. I'm going through data from 37 drug trials. The problem is, in some of them there are very few deaths. For example, 3 deaths / 409 in treatment and 7 deaths / 425 in placebo.

I am very concerned that the number of deaths is much too small, and that I shouldn't include these trials in my analysis. I don't know if there's a point in seeing if the difference between proportions is significant. I've read of studies where halfway through, the differences were EXTREMELY significant, but by the end, there was no difference.

Am I justified in worrying, or should I just do Fisher's test and accept whatever p values I get? I believe it's more appropriate for this scenario than a regular p value?

The only thing I can think of is to do a power analysis to find the required sample size, and then compare the results from the power analysis to the trial. If the trial groups are smaller than the sample size recommended by the power analysis, then I can assume this data belongs in the trash? For example,

Or rather, would it indicate that if there is an effect of the drug, it is so small that it is very impractical?

In case it helps, here's the R code and outputs that I have so far

> x <- 3
>
> y <- 7
>
> n1 <- 409
>
> n2 <- 425
>
> p1 <- x/n1
>
> p2 <- y/n2
>
> p1
>
> [1] 0.007334963
>
> p2
>
> [1] 0.01647059
>
> p <- (x+y)/ (n1+n2)
>
> z<- (p1-p2) / (sqrt(p*(1-p))*sqrt(1/n1+1/n2))
>
> pvalue <- 1 - pnorm(abs(z))
>
> pvalue
>
> [1] 0.1128036
>
> fisher.test( cbind( c(3,3), c(145-3, 155-3) ) )

```
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
```

> data:  cbind(c(3, 3), c(145 - 3, 155 - 3))
>   p-value = 1
>   alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
>   95 percent confidence interval:
>   0.1410036 8.1230482
>   sample estimates:
>   odds ratio 
>    1.070149

Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation

```
          n = 15578.73
         p1 = 0.007334963
         p2 = 0.01647059
  sig.level = 1e-04
      power = 0.9999
alternative = one.sided
```

Any comments, criticism or suggestions much appreciated! Even if you could just point me in the right direction! Thank you so much